# Is there any way to add incremental number in all rows of html code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have drop-down (select -> option) in HTML and one select contains a lot of options. Is there any way to add incremental/unique number to each option/row.

e.g: in id, I want to assign incremental/unique number automatically to each id.

```
<select name="select_data"> 
    <option id="1" value="index">index</option>
    <option id="2" value="one">one</option>
    <option id="3" value="two">two</option>
    <option id="4" value="three">three</option>
    <option id="5" value="four">four</option>
</select>
```

**Note:** Editor is VSCODE.

I don't want this via jquery that may increment in browser as output. I just want it only in editor.

Comment: I believe you can probably do it by defining your own snippet. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: I can think of other ways to increment a number, although I would probably do something like write an autohotkey script to do it if on windows. But I think you probably don't want to have to write the options out by hand and then just autoincrement the id, because at that point why not just write the id by hand also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **counter-increment** of CSS if you do not want to use JS functions.

```
 body {
  /* Set "my-sec-counter" to 0 */
  counter-reset: my-sec-counter;
}

 select > option {
  /* Increment "my-sec-counter" by 1 */
  counter-increment: my-sec-counter;
  content: "Section " counter(my-sec-counter) ". ";
}
```

You can look at: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_counter-reset3
to understand better what I tried to do so.

Comment: if its possible to add unique number to each option via jquery, please let me know.

Comment: I don't want these unique numbers as output. I need these only in editor (vscode)

Comment: You can use  Math.random() function then. I am unable to understand your aim properly. Do you want to add id's to options incrementally or what?

Comment: its same like if we press ctrl+shift+L, to edit all selected rows simultaneously in vscode. I need same thing but in incremental way.

Comment: This extension seems like it does what you need. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albymor.increment-selection